# I need Help How to add Spinner a function that records the table to export data in Excel? Angular material

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to add spinner and remove it when I finish executing the "exportTable" function As shown in the example:

**ts:**

```
  Export(){
    this.spinner.show();
    this.ExpTable.exportTable('xlsx', {fileName:'Cat_claves_presup', sheet: 'Hoja1', Props: {Author: 'Administrador'}});
    this.spinner.hide();
  }
```

**HTML:**

```
<mat-toolbar>
<button mat-button (click)="Export()">
  <mat-icon color="primary">unarchive</mat-icon>Exportar
</button>
<button mat-button>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filtrar por">
  </mat-form-field>
</button>
</mat-toolbar>
<div>
<mat-table matTableExporter  #exporter="matTableExporter" [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort style="overflow-x: scroll !important; display: grid" class="scroll" hiddenColumns="[1,3,4]">
<ng-container matColumnDef="id_clav_p">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="columna1"> No. </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="columna1" > {{row.id_clav_p}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

The problem is that the Spinner is not shown () that is to say the component that shows the waiting process and simply executes the function which runs through the mat-table to export the data. I have tried to add callbacks, subscribe and even setTimeout but I can't get it to show the spinner first, then run the code it exports and finally hide the spinner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ExportDataToExcel(){
  const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet=XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(this.table.nativeElement);
  const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
  XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Sheet1');

  /* save to file */
  XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'SheetJS.xlsx');
  }
```

Steps for ngx loader you can refer this link : https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-spinner

Comment: I have used that function but unfortunately it has not worked for me.
This is because all my angular project I have used angular-material and from what I have seen this function only works with the native html. and the function that works for me perfectly is "exportTable"